# DRF: How to access "context" inside custom DecimalField class?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, field

I am subclassing the DecimalField class from Django RestFramework and need to access `context`.  Formatting for decimal fields includes settings that are user-selectable, so I need to access the user object (which, I assume, should be inside `context`) inside the `to_representation()` method.

Via debug, I've looked at all properties of `self` inside my CustomDecimalField class, but, of course, I can't see class methods, so I don't know if there's an appropriate "get" method to get context.  I've tried `self.context` (as a property), `self.get_context()`, and `self.getcontext()`, but none worked.

I found this announcement re: `require_context`:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.11-announcement/
...but it seems to be valid only for validation and default value methods.

This seems like such a simple thing; hard to believe it is so difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually set the user inside the context. So, in your view:

```
serializer = YourSerializer(your_data, context={'user': request.user})
```

And you will then be able to access it in your to_representation() method:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    user = self.context.get("user")
```

Please see [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Mickael.  At about the same time you were posting your answer, I realized I was looking for it in the wrong method.  I was looking at ```self``` in the ```__init__()``` method, instead of actually in ```to_reqpresentation()```.